# Determining the kernel and image of each of the following maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider:

$\mathcal{P}: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by orthogonal projection onto the line $y=3x$

and

$\mathcal{S}:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by rotation anti-clockwise about the origin by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

How do I use **geometric arguments** to determine the image and kernel of each of the maps $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{P}\circ\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}\circ\mathcal{P}$?

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't have much of a clue on how to go about doing this question.

Answer (score 1):

If points in $\Bbb R^2$ are orthogonally projected onto $y = 3x$, then the image is exactly that line. That is,

$$\text{Im}(\mathcal P) = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y = 3x\}.$$

The kernel is the set of points that project onto the origin, which is the set of all points perpendicular to the line at the origin.

$$\text{Ker}(\mathcal P) = \left\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y = -\frac{1}{3}x\right\}.$$

---

For $\mathcal S$, since rotation is a bijective mapping, the image is all of $\Bbb R^2$. To find a point $(x_1,y_1)$ that maps to $(x_2,y_2)$, simply rotate $(x_2,y_2)$ clockwise by $\frac\pi2$.

Ther kernel is the trivial set $\{(0,0)\}$ since nothing else maps to the origin.

---

For $\mathcal P \circ \mathcal S$, you rotate and then project and for $\mathcal S \circ \mathcal P$, you project and then rotate. In both cases, your image and kernel will be lines.